# ListView lagging with ViewHolder and Cached images

Tags: android, listview, lag

Another day, another question! I am currently creating a music player for an assignment for school. From day 1 when I made and populated my ListView, the ListView has been lagging like crazy. A couple of days ago I started caching my images with a LruCache, but no performance increase could be noticed. Today I added in ViewHolders, but again, no performance increase whatsoever.

In my ListView, either a folder item or a song item can be show. Folder items get an Album Image in their view (next to 2 textviews). Right now it are some hardcoded images drawn from my drawable resources (Size ranges between 15KB and 55 KB). A song item has just 4 TextViews. When the list only has song items, the lag is a little less, but still too much.

Currently there are about 10 items max in the ListView. Underneath is the ArrayAdapter used to create the list. I'm very new to Android, so any help/tip is appreciated, even if it isn't related to the issue.

```
public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache;
    private ArrayList<Integer> myFolderSongCounts;

    ViewHolderSongs holderSongs;
    ViewHolderFolders holderFolders;

    public SongAdapter(Context context, List objects, ArrayList<Integer> folderSongCounts) {
        super(context, 0, objects);

        myFolderSongCounts = folderSongCounts;

        /*
        *
        * CACHE EXAMPLE FROM
        * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586977/listview-scroll-lagging-when-images-is-shown
        * BY USER Lam Do
        *
        * */

        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
                // number of items.
                return bitmap.getRowBytes() / 1024;
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        File song = (File) getItem(position);

        Log.d("SongAdapter Position: ", ""+ position);

        Listen main = (Listen) getContext().getApplicationContext();
        Typeface custom_font = main.getCustom_font();

        //if its an mp3 file, show a song list item
        if(song.getName().substring(song.getName().length()-4,song.getName().length()).equals(".mp3")) {
            Mp3File mp3file = null;
            MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            retriever.setDataSource(song.getPath());
            try {
                if(convertView == null){
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.songs_list_item, parent, false);

                    holderSongs = new ViewHolderSongs();
                    holderSongs.txt_song_album = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.song_album);
                    holderSongs.txt_song_artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
                    holderSongs.txt_song_duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.song_duration);
                    holderSongs.txt_song_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.song_name);

                    convertView.setTag(holderSongs);
                }
                else {
                    holderSongs = (ViewHolderSongs) convertView.getTag();
                }

                mp3file = new Mp3File(song);

                String album = mp3file.getId3v2Tag().getAlbum();
                String artist = mp3file.getId3v2Tag().getAlbumArtist();

                int durationInMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
                int durationInSeconds = durationInMilliseconds/1000;
                int durationMinutes = durationInSeconds/60;
                String durationSeconds = (durationInSeconds%60 > 10) ? "" + durationInSeconds%60 : "0" + durationInSeconds%60;
                String duration = durationMinutes + ":" + durationSeconds;

                holderSongs.txt_song_name.setText(song.getName().substring(0, song.getName().length() - 4));
                holderSongs.txt_song_album.setText(getValidValue(album, "undefined"));
                holderSongs.txt_song_artist.setText(getValidValue(artist, "undefined"));
                holderSongs.txt_song_duration.setText(getValidValue(duration, "0:00"));

                holderSongs.txt_song_name.setTypeface(custom_font);
                holderSongs.txt_song_album.setTypeface(custom_font);
                holderSongs.txt_song_artist.setTypeface(custom_font);
                holderSongs.txt_song_duration.setTypeface(custom_font);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedTagException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidDataException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //if its a folder, show a folder list item
        else {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.folders_list_item, parent, false);

                holderFolders = new ViewHolderFolders();

                holderFolders.amount_of_songs = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.amount_of_songs);
                holderFolders.folder_name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.folder_name);
                holderFolders.folder_image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.folder_image);

                convertView.setTag(holderFolders);
            }
            else {
                holderFolders = (ViewHolderFolders) convertView.getTag();
            }


            int amountOfSongs = myFolderSongCounts.get(position);

            holderFolders.folder_name.setText(song.getName());
            holderFolders.amount_of_songs.setText(amountOfSongs + " songs");

            holderFolders.folder_name.setTypeface(custom_font);
            holderFolders.amount_of_songs.setTypeface(custom_font);

            if(position == 0){

                Bitmap bmp = getBitmapFromMemCache("perfectlychilled");
                if (bmp == null) {
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(convertView.getResources(), R.drawable.perfectly_chilled);
                    addBitmapToMemoryCache("perfectlychilled", bmp);
                }

                holderFolders.folder_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
            else if(position == 1){
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmapFromMemCache("insurgency");
                if (bmp == null) {
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(convertView.getResources(), R.drawable.insurgency);
                    addBitmapToMemoryCache("insurgency", bmp);
                }

                holderFolders.folder_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
            else {
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmapFromMemCache("default");
                if (bmp == null) {
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(convertView.getResources(), R.drawable.folderdefault);
                    addBitmapToMemoryCache("default", bmp);
                }

                holderFolders.folder_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
        }



        return convertView;
    }

    public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
            cache.put(key, bitmap);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
        return cache.get(key);
    }

    static class ViewHolderSongs {
        TextView txt_song_name;
        TextView txt_song_album;
        TextView txt_song_artist;
        TextView txt_song_duration;
    }

    static class ViewHolderFolders {
        TextView folder_name;
        TextView amount_of_songs;
        ImageView folder_image;
    }
}
```

songs_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@color/backgroundGray"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="70dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/song_name"
            android:textColor="@color/textBlack"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end" />

        <TextView
            android:text="3:26"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="@color/textBlack"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/song_name"
            android:id="@+id/song_duration"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/song_artist"
            android:textColor="@color/textGray"
            android:width="190dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_below="@id/song_name"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Sabaton" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Hell is upon us"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/textGray"
            android:width="190dp"
            android:id="@+id/song_album"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_below="@id/song_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/song_artist"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

folders_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@color/backgroundGray"

    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/folder_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="115dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"

        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/folder_name"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:elevation="14dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/textBlack"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/amount_of_songs"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:textColor="@color/textGray"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nested layouts are bad for performances (no marvel that you get lags!). Better try using RelativeLayouts. And the ImageView is useless, since the image can be included into the TextView, as a **compound drawable**.

Comment: I'll try with relative layouts asap then, and I had never even heard of compound drawables! Thank you!

Comment: I changed songs_list_item.xml to use just a RelativeLayout with 4 TextViews in it, but the lag is still as bad...

Comment: Can't tell, without seeing the new layouts. Maybe ConstraintLayout might be a little faster than RelativeLayout (so they say). And/Or you could use a RecyclerView - which is said to be faster than ListView.

Comment: I edited the new Layout in (only songs_list_item.xml). I'm running short on time, and RecyclerView looks like its a whole lot of work to replace the ListView with it... If I can't fix it with just ListView I'll have to place my priorities elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html

--setDataSource
Sets the data source (FileDescriptor) to use. It is the caller's responsibility to close the file descriptor. It is safe to do so as soon as this call returns. Call this method before the rest of the methods in this class. **This method may be time-consuming.**

You have to retrieve songs' information outside the adapter and pass raw information into the adapter.

Comment: I'll give this a try!

Comment: It improved performance very slightly, but it doesnt seem to be the main cause of the issue...

Comment: So now there is no try/catch for IOException inside the adapter::getView right? I am saying that as an identifier of the complete IO operations removal inside the adapter.

Comment: Yeah the try - catch is gone